# Google analytics Avg session details

Tags: google-analytics

just wanted to check how the "Avg session duration" is calculated?  Attached screenshot shows 3 pages and their respective Avg. session duration which is 19:09, 00:00, and 00:00. but the Avg session duration at the top is 09:34?

how is the 09:34 calculated?

thanks!
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OXss.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the documentation:   [Avg. Session Duration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_avgsessionduration)

> ga:avgSessionDuration
>
> Web View Name: Avg. Session Duration
>
> The average duration of user sessions represented in total seconds.
>
> Calculation: ga:sessionDuration / ga:sessions

Comment: thanks. I get that bit. but what i dont get is if avg session duration for 3 pages is 19:09, 00:00, and 00:00 respectively, then how is the overal avg. session duration 09:34? thanks

Comment: Try and display session duration and you will be able to figure out the calculation. https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=vgYX2_UYRe-TneuUlmbjcQ

Comment: thanks for the pointer! that helps. i looked at the session duration for each and calculated the weighted average which is quite close to the overall avg. session duration in GA report (different of about 3 to 4 sec).

Comment: Just remember stuff like average calculation isn't completed processing for 24 hours don't look at todays data.